# Issue installing turtlebot3 simulation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, simulation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I switched from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 16.04 and try to completely remove ros indigo and install ros kinetic and gazebo9
I followed a guide to install .
This is a lists of my command on terminal:

cd ~/catkin_ws/src

1. git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations.git
2. git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_msgs.git
3. git clone https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3.git
4. cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make && source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

cd ..

catkin_make

This is the last part of output

```
Scanning dependencies of target turtlebot3_fake_node
[ 70%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_cpp
[ 80%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_eus
[ 89%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_lisp
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so', needed by '/home/me/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_gazebo/turtlebot3_drive'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4337: recipe for target 'turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_drive.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_drive.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so', needed by '/home/me/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_bringup/turtlebot3_diagnostics'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1680: recipe for target 'turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [turtlebot3/turtlebot3_bringup/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_diagnostics.dir/all] Error 2
[ 89%] Built target turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/liblog4cxx.so', needed by '/home/me/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_fake/turtlebot3_fake_node'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 91%] Building CXX object turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_fake/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_fake_node.dir/src/turtlebot3_fake.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3683: recipe for target 'turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_fake/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_fake_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_fake/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_fake_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Suggestions? I'm a newbie on ROS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288496/issue-installing-turtlebot3-simulation-on-ubuntu-16.04/) by [kenhero](https://answers.ros.org/users/34341/kenhero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2018-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes i just saw that thread before posting here but after 2 hours of search i think that the problem in my case is that i still have indigo folder together with kinetic folder  in /opt/ros.
Obv i unistalled indigo (or maybe i try to remove it and all his dependencies) before start to install kinetic but i read somewhere it's very difficult .
In any case i have this folder and i can't delete.
Also during catkin_make now i have some warnings always like this:

CMake Warning at gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/CMakeLists.txt:72 (add_library):
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target gazebo_ros_api_plugin
because there is a cycle in the constraint graph:

```
dir 0 is [/opt/ros/kinetic/lib]
  dir 2 must precede it due to runtime library [libroscpp.so]
dir 1 is [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-7/plugins]
dir 2 is [/opt/ros/indigo/lib]
  dir 0 must precede it due to runtime library [libroslib.so]
```

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

CMake Warning at gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/CMakeLists.txt:78 (add_library):
Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target
gazebo_ros_paths_plugin because there is a cycle in the constraint graph:

```
dir 0 is [/opt/ros/kinetic/lib]
  dir 2 must precede it due to runtime library [libroscpp.so]
dir 1 is [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gazebo-7/plugins]
dir 2 is [/opt/ros/indigo/lib]
  dir 0 must precede it due to runtime library [libroslib.so]
```

Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.

EDIT:
ok, I solved brutally deleting indigo folder with root privileges. I don't know why unistall  leaves it

---

Originally posted by [kenhero](https://answers.ros.org/users/34341/kenhero/) with karma: 31 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0